# Latest gem version not installing

Tags: ruby, github, bundler, facebook-business-sdk

If you look at the [facebookbusiness gem](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk), you will notice that currently the latest version is 0.4.0.1

However running `gem install 'facebookbusiness'` gives:
Successfully installed facebookbusiness-0.3.3.4
1 gem installed

Trying to specify a version in the gem file with `gem 'facebookbusiness', '~> 0.4.0.1'` results in `Could not find gem 'facebookbusiness (~> 0.4.0.1)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.`

When I type `gem env` I get:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.4
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-darwin17]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@rails
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@rails/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-17
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@rails
     - /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - ~/bin
     - /Users/me/.npm-packages/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@rails/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/go/bin
     - /opt/X11/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gem install` pulls the published gem from rubygems.org. Just because a developer has pushed a newer version to their git repository doesn't mean that they've also published the newer version of the gem to rubygems.

In this case, that's exactly what's happened. The latest published version at rubygems can be seen here: https://rubygems.org/gems/facebookbusiness/

It may be that the version in their git repository isn't stable, or isn't ready for release for some other reason like the documentation isn't ready for it, or the APIs it relies on aren't yet publicly available, or is undergoing a security review before being published, or any other reason you can think of. If you want to use it anyway, it's fairly straightforward to do so in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'facebookbusiness', git: 'git@github.com:facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk'
```

Then run `bundle install` to pull the gem directly from GitHub.

Comment: Thank you! I learned something new. Just a note, gem 'facebookbusiness', github: 'facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk' worked for me and not git: 'git@github.com:facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk'

Comment: The `git: 'git@github.com:org/repo'` syntax is relying on SSH and your keys being setup for GitHub, the `github: 'org/repo'` syntax is doing a straight HTTPS call.

Answer (score 1):

`http://` and `git://` URLs are insecure. A man-in-the-middle attacker could tamper with the code as you check it out, and potentially supply you with malicious code instead of the code you meant to check out. Because the `:github` shortcut uses a `git://` URL in Bundler `1.x` versions, we recommend using `HTTPS` URLs or overriding the `:github` shortcut with your own `HTTPS` git source.

**Not good way to adding gem in your Gemfile**

```
gem 'facebookbusiness', git: 'git@github.com:facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk'
```

**Good way to adding gem in your Gemfile**

```
gem 'facebookbusiness', github: 'facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk'
```

**Better way to adding gem in your Gemfile with branch**

```
gem 'facebookbusiness', github: 'facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk', branch: 'branch_name'
```

or

```
gem 'facebookbusiness', github: 'facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk', ref: 'ref_number'
```

or

```
gem 'facebookbusiness', github: 'facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk', tag: 'tag_number'
```

For security point of view and prevent the future failures don't take to `master` branch code.

I hope that helpful.

Comment: To clarify, `git: 'git@github.com:org/repo'` *is* a good way (and is probably the best way) because it uses SSH. More [here](https://bundler.io/guides/git.html).

Comment: Please read security section in your above link https://bundler.io/guides/git.html#security

Comment: You’re confusing `git@` and `git://`. Read the whole document.